# A connection to (...) was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I'm having a warning message constantly, despite my code seems to be good. The message is:

```
WARNING: A connection to http://someurl.com was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
java.lang.Throwable: response.body().close()
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.getStackTraceForCloseable(Platform.java:148)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.captureCallStackTrace(RealCall.java:89)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:73)
    at com.example.HTTPSClientReferenceRate.runClient(HTTPSClientReferenceRate.java:78)
    at com.example.HTTPSClientReferenceRate.main(HTTPSClientReferenceRate.java:137)
```

I'm working with Java 8. I've tried with the traditional `try-catch` and with this approach (`try-with-resources`):

```
boolean repeatRequest = true;

while(repeatRequest) {
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    try (Response response = call.execute()){
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            log.error("Error with the response: " + response.message());
            continue;
        }
        ResponseBody body = response.body();
        if (body == null){
            log.error("Error when getting body from the response: " + response.message());
            continue;
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(body.charStream());

        //...DATA HANDLING

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error Connecting to the stream. Retrying... Error message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In fact, the first **if** line is never called, I always have an exception, so I cannot understand why the response/body is not closed by the try-with-resources block

I've tried this option as well, but it didn't work either:

```
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) { ... }
```

**EDIT**

I've reduced my code, and I'm still having the same error, this is even weirder:

```
boolean repeatRequest = true;

while(repeatRequest) {
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    try (Response response = call.execute()){
        //NOTHING
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error Connecting to the stream. Retrying... Error message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

I've tried with the traditional `try-catch` but I'm still having the same issue:

```
boolean repeatRequest = true;

while(repeatRequest) {
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = call.execute();
        try (ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
            //Nothing...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error Connecting to the stream. Retrying... Error message: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (response != null){
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this :  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

Comment: @btreport I've tried that before without luck, I'll add it to my post description.

Comment: which version of java you working on?

Comment: @ErHarshRathore I'm working with Java 8

Comment: As per my knowledge java 8 is not able to read this try (Response response = call.execute()){}    instead you should try the declaration and definition separately like Response response; try (response = call.execute())

Comment: @ErHarshRathore try-with-resources was added in Java 7, so that's not the issue here.

Comment: try(Declaration + Definition) {} feature is first introduced in java 9

Comment: @ErHarshRathore maybe you're confused about this, in fact, ```Response response; try (response = call.execute())``` is not valid.

Comment: @Villat yes I am getting little bit confused. Sorry

Answer (score 15):

As per [`Response.close()` javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#close--):

> It is an error to close a response that is not eligible for a body. This includes the responses returned from `cacheResponse`, `networkResponse`, and `priorResponse()`.

Perhaps your code should look like below, as per [Github comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311#issuecomment-179521327):

```
while (repeatRequest) {
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();
    try (ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Karol, I've edited my post, you could see that the error seems to be somewhere else, any ideas?

Comment: You are closing `Response` with `try-with-resource` block. The docs says not to do this for some responses, try the code suggested on Github.

Comment: Karol, I've added a new edit to my post, am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: @Villat I have updated the example you have to add exception handling to match your method signature.

Comment: I've updated the **edit 2**, still having the issue. I tried debugging, and the code jumps from `response = call.execute();` to the **catch** block, and the `response` is always **null**... despite of that, the error is still happening

Comment: @Villat what is the version of OkHttp you are using?

Comment: I'm using 3.10.0, and I've also tried with 3.14.2 and 4.0.1 without luck

Comment: I use retrofit, it automatically should close everything

Comment: What happens if you don't close it? Memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

When using Kotlin, this can easily be handled by closing the `respoonse.body` if it is non-null. If a body is present, closing it closes the source but if it is not present, closing is not required. For example:

```
                    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                    // check for response.isSuccessful here, or read the body if required
                    response.body?.close()
```