# URLConnection error: /OkHttpClient: A connection to https://www.google.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

Tags: android, response, urlconnection

I'm getting the above error while using the following code. Error occurs when using retrieveURL() method of following class. I tried to find the method to close URLConnection but was unsuccessful to do so. What am I missing here?

```
public class Url {
    public static String retrieveURL(String url)
    {
        if(connectURL(url)!=null) {
            URLConnection urlConn = connectURL(url);
            urlConn.getHeaderFields();
            return urlConn.getURL().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static URLConnection connectURL(String strURL) {
        URLConnection conn =null;
        try {
            URL inputURL = new URL(strURL);
            conn = inputURL.openConnection();
        }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Duplicated] Take a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260220/a-connection-to-was-leaked-did-you-forget-to-close-a-response-body)

Comment: @gcantoni No, that question does not use URLConnection.